# How do I pass a function that takes a float and returns a float to another function?

Tags: java, function, pointers

I am trying to write a "map" function on one of my classes in Java. How do I pass a function that takes a float and return a float to another function? Something like this:

```
void map( MapFn fn ) 
{
    for ( int  i = 0 ; i < this.rows; ++i ) 
    {
        for ( int  j = 0 ; j < this.cols; ++j ) 
        {
            this.inner[i][j] = fn(this.inner[i][j])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could maybe try Converter<Float> or define your own Functionnal interface, exemple : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Stream_How_to/Lambda_API/Create_Converter_functional_interface.htm

Comment: Are you asking how to write a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) in general or how to write a Java [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)?

Comment: Or do you want to pass the function `fn` as parameter?

Comment: @Modul Tollens - I am trying to pass function to a function... I want to apply a function to all elements of an array....more like what "map" does.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments by @boly38, the `java.util.function` package is your friend (or just functional interfaces/lambdas in general) here.  For example, it provides the [`DoubleUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleUnaryOperator.html) class.  Accepting an instance of this as your method argument and using the [`applyAsDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleUnaryOperator.html#applyAsDouble-double-) method will do (effectively) what you want.

There is none provided *specifically* for `float` however.  If you need one you can always define your own:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FloatUnaryOperator {
    float applyAsFloat(float in);
}
```

So having your method be:

```
public void doThing(final DoubleUnaryOperator mapper) {
    for (final double d : someArray) {
        System.out.println(mapper.applyAsDouble(d));
    }
}
```

---

Instances of these can be created via lambdas (or any other means) such as `f -> f * 2.0f;` (which will double any given `float`).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand Java, but basically you are asking me to create a class and pass that object to the function and then use that class' member function? Thats not what I want to do. I want to pass a function as the parameter not a class ( or interface). Is there a way to pass a function (that takes a float and returns a float) to another function? 
For example, I would like to do something like what C# delegates do....

Comment: That's what this answer does.  As in the `doThing` method, you have passed a function (which takes a `double` and returns a `double`).  You can _invoke_ this function on a `double` using its `applyAsDouble` method.  The 'create a class' part was if you _explicitly_ required it to be based on `float`s (i.e. upcasting to `double` would not be acceptable).

Comment: @JimGreen: [Here](https://ideone.com/zZVAFl) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean, but I think you want to do this:

```
public float map(float value) {
    float mappedValue = value * 20;
    return mappedValue;
}
```

Comment: Sorry...I need to know how do I define the function pointer?